# How do I fix my SQL syntax error in my express POST handler?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

First time here posting.

I keep receiving the following error whenever I send a post request with the handler in the code.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check that manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1)' at line 1.
```

```
app.post('/',function(req,res,next){
var context = {};
pool.query("INSERT INTO workouts (`name`, `reps`, `weight`,`date`, 'lbs') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs], function(err, result){
    if(err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('table', context);
});
```

I'm doing this for a course project, and I can't figure out what the problem is.
Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: Apparently, I needed to changed the date to be in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you might want to try some SQL parser/validator, like https://github.com/forward/sql-parser

Comment: You have written 'lbs' with ' instead of `

Comment: I originally had backticks for lbs, and that's when the error shown was persisting. Put single quotations when messing around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it on this way

```
pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO workouts (name, reps, weight, date, lbs) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)',
      [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs],
      if(err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('table', context);
   });
});
```

This way you have prepared statement ready for Posgres, btw in general this is wrong approach to pass values directly from request to SQL (SQL injection) also for debugging purpose you can always print SQL and then try it directly in SQL and see exact error if this or any other SQL lib do not return proper error.

In case that you are using MySQL then should be like this

```
pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO workouts SET name = ?, reps =?, weight=?, date=?, lbs=?',
      [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs],
      if(err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('table', context);
   });
});
```

Comment: more samples here https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: using your MySQL suggestions, I get the same error except instead of '1)' it says 'lbs = 1'. Would the 1 need to be sent from my AJAX request as a string?

Answer (score 0):

What sql library are you using?

I think it may be two things:

1. You don't need the quotation marks around your column names

```
INSERT INTO workouts 
(name, reps, weight, date, lbs) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

2. Depending on your sql library, I think you will need to adjust your replacements `(? => $1)`:

```
INSERT INTO workouts 
(name, reps, weight, date, lbs) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL if that's what you mean by library.

Comment: I've tried removing the backticks and still receive the same error.

Comment: Ah, with MSQL I think you will need to do `name = ?, reps = ?...` instead of the $1, $2, $3

Comment: Done it that way. Get same error but with ' lbs = 1' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is MariaDB or MySQL, and looks like you have single normal quotes around lbs. Change from single quote **'**

```
INSERT INTO workouts (`name`, `reps`, `weight`,`date`, **'lbs'**)
```

to back quotes **`**

```
INSERT INTO workouts (`name`, `reps`, `weight`,`date`, `lbs`)
```

Comment: Originally, I had "lbs" with backticks and received the syntax error shown in the photo. I accidentally added single quotations while messing around. The error is also present even after removing all backticks.

Comment: @JuzSumGoi12 - you also have date field in the table. Is the data for it instance of Date? if so, try to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss, if I remember correctly query function converts parameters to inline values using toString() function.

Comment: Does JSON.stringify not convert it properly?

Comment: I just tried: "{\"date\":\"2021-06-03T19:52:45.664Z\"}", obviously it's ISO format, and MySQL 8 (I have 8.0.15) does not understand it

Comment: Though, for me it gives **Incorrect date value** not a syntax error. Probably you might want to split the query into lines by entering \n just to locate the error...

Comment: Just a question, do all the inserted values have to be a string?

Comment: not necessarily, numbers and boolean should go as well, Buffer for binaries

Comment: So, I solved the problem after what you said about the date. After console logging, what I was sending it was indeed sending ISO formatted dates. I decided to change the date of what I'm sending via AJAX request to "YYYY-DD-MM" format and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
`INSERT INTO workouts 
(name, reps, weight, xdate) 
VALUES ('${name}', '${reps}', '${weight}', '${xdate}')`
```